# How to set random name for install directory for msi (wix)

Tags: vbscript, wix, windows-installer

Wix developers!

Is it possible to specify random name for install directory name with the help of property or vbscript custom action?...

I have the following Product.wxs:

```html
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Client">
          <Component Id="ProductComponent">
            <File Id="File001" Source="..\Release\One.dll" />
          </Component>
...
```

It is prepare install directory like: 
C:\Program Files(x86)\Client

I need like this
C:\Program Files(x86)\234wfdasdqaw
where "234wfdasdqaw" random string which generated in every case when
a) run msi for installation
b) and if admin is not set the INSTALLLOCATION via command line.

Is it possible?
thank you.

Comment: Yes, create an immediate action which will modify the INSTALLLOCATION property.

Comment: I've been writing installers for 20 years and have never seen such a design.  Can you describe why you need to do this?

Comment: ok so I must create immediate custom action? Which parametr "before" or "after" must be set for custom action.. please show example

Comment: I need to hide directory because it will admin package.

Comment: How does giving it a random name "hide" it?   Wouldn't you be better served to just change the permissions of the folder so that only  Administrators and SYSTEM can access it?

Comment: Hi, Christopher! It is a just additinal security moment. For example there is an antivirus dr web cureit. If you download it from server you will see random exe name. I want to develope msi which will unpack files in random directory for install. It will allow others users does not to know where worked files of my product were installed... Msi will have admin property (hiden propertty msi) and directory will be hiden with the help of driver..

Comment: Christopher, if it difficalt, can we disscuss this task as project on elance.com?

Comment: But if andmin will specify INSTALLLOCATION as a parametr of command line, msi must install in the specified location.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom action to randomly generate the string and then a type 51 (set property) custom action to set INSTALLLOCATION to a computed value if 1) it doesn't already have a value and 2) the product isn't already installed.  I would not do this in the root of ProgramFilesFolder as that would be very messy.  At least do it in  [ProgramFilesFolder]Company or [ProgramFilesFolder]Product.  Your question makes me wonder if you plan on installing this MSI more then once.  Be aware that it takes special tricks to install an MSI multiple times.

Comment: Hello, Christopher Painter!

Comment: Thank you. But can you show example of such custom action in wxs?.. I can generate random string only in my custom action dll...

Comment: extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UINT __stdcall SetupInstallLocationDir(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
 HRESULT hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "SetupInstallLocationDir");

 MsiSetPropertyW(hInstall, L"INSTALLLOCATION", L"C:\\zzzzzzz");

 return WcaFinalize(ERROR_SUCCESS);
}